# Trying to modify this javascript code to either reduce the size of the pop up or close when the user clicks out side the box

Tags: javascript, html, height, popupwindow, mailing-list

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us13.list-manage.com","uuid":"f773ae618a7d6e4a66826d6b8","lid":"f1c0b4007d"}) })</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet, since it's a mailchimp popup with no real way to edit that, would be to make the changes you're looking for with css or jquery. After you've implemented it, inspect the element to get the class or id, then in your css or jquery file make the changes the you want.

Alternatively, you could make your own pop and link it with your mailchimp. While this may be the cleanest solution, it would be far more time consuming.

Hope this helps.